# How do I find out what Intel Integrated Graphics Controller I'm using?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics, flash, intel-graphics

I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I want to know what version of the graphics controller I'm using. The motherboard for my system is a Gateway 4000856 Thrasher. What I do know is my controller is from Intel.

My reasoning is for this is so I can get the proper drivers and finally get Adobe Flash content to work properly (the content will display squashed, with a greenish-purple).

Comment: **lspci | grep VGA** and **sudo lshw -c video** should give you enough info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following in a terminal window:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA
```

The output should show the required info and the driver in use.

Example:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) Graphics Controller [8086:8108] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02c6]
    Kernel driver in use: gma500
```

Comment: I found the graphics controller type. Thanks. --->   [0300]: Intel Corporation 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device [8086:2562] (rev 01)